# Why is Express isn't able to find ejs in netlify lambda serverless

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless, netlify

I am trying to deploy a project with using serverless http with netlify. So far I have gotten the deployment to be successful, but the page says "Internal server error" and when I check the console, it says "Cannot find module ejs". I have tried to reinstall ejs and express even globally and have moved the "node_modules" folder a level above, but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const router = require('./routes')
const path = require('path')
const ejs = require('ejs');

const serverless = require('serverless-http');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/.netlify/functions/index', router)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

So I put **app.set('view engine', 'ejs')** and it says that it cannot find **ejs**

However, this does work on normal

> node index.js

but I don't know why it isn't working here.

Help would be appreciated, thank You so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to say where the folder for the views exist

This should fix it

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); \\ views being the name of the folder in the root dir
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```